# How the following scenario be achieved using smart contracts?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-design, contract-invocation

Assuming we have two parties (A & B). How the following scenario be achieved using smart contracts?

User **A** will deposit some funds (**x** coins).
user **A** can receive penalty funds from user **B**, So user **B** will also deposit funds (**y** coins).

if, within certain time (time locked),  **B** provides a preimage to a certain hash value. Then, he gets the **x** coins and the **B** coins (**y** coins) back. otherwise **A** can get his coins back and also the B'coins (**y** coins) ?

A related nice answer is in here:

1.[Zero knowledge contingent payment on etherum?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/65884/zero-knowledge-contingent-payment-on-etherum/65885?noredirect=1#comment81178_65885)

2. [Is the following scenario doable by a smart contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/66835/is-the-following-scenario-doable-by-a-smart-contract/66838?noredirect=1#comment80742_66838)